# Is there a Lipschitz continuous bijection between a ray and the whole real line?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

my question is already in the title, I state it here in an equivalent way:

**Question:** Is there a bijective Lipschitz continuous function $f \colon (0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$?

I think the answer is no but can't find a rigorous argument to support this.

I stumbled upon this question in the context of partitions: Suppose you have a continuous function $\phi$ defined on the real line whose limit at $-\infty$ is zero. Thus, by defining $\phi(-\infty)=0$, it can be extended to a function on $\mathbb{R} \cup \{-\infty\}$. It would be nice to define some kind of partition of an interval $[-\infty,x]$ to approximate $\phi$ by simple functions as, unfortunately, the "standard" way of approximating $\phi$ with simple functions $\phi_n$ supported by $[x-n,x]$ doesn't seem to work in my case. I had to take a Lebesgue-style approach and defined partitions $-\infty = t_0^n < t_1^n < \dots$ by $t_0^n=-\infty$ and $$t_{k+1}^n = \inf \{ t > t_k^n \mid | \phi_t - \phi_{t_{k}^n} | \geq 2^{-n} \}.$$
As the function $\phi$ I'm looking at has infinite variation over each interval, the numbers $t_k^n$ are finite for $k \geq 1$ and, because of continuity, $\lim_{k \to \infty} t^n_k = \infty$. Thus, for any $x$ this yields a finite partition of $[-\infty,x]$ (in the sense that you partition $[-\infty,x]$ into finitely many parts) whose mesh goes to zero if you let $n$ tend to infinity (again because of continuity). If an $f$ as stated in my question above would exists, I could avoid this construction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.

Suppose $f : (0, + \infty) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is injective, Lipschitz continuous. Then $f$ can be extended to $0$ putting
$$f(0) = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$$

But now it is clear that if $\sup f = + \infty$, then $\inf f \neq - \infty$, since $f$ is monotonic (injective implies monotonic).

Answer (score 4):

No, such an $f$ cannot exist.

Let $f\colon (0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ an injective Lipschitz function with Lipschitz constant $L$. We want to show that $f$ cannot be surjective.

Let $\xi = f(1)$. If $f(2) > \xi$, then by injectivity we have $f(x) < \xi \iff x < 1$, and hence $f(x) > \xi - L$ for all $x$. For $x\geqslant 1$, we even have $f(x)\geqslant \xi$, and for $x < 1$, we see $f(x) \geqslant f(1) - L\lvert 1-x\rvert > \xi - L$. If $f(2) < \xi$, we similarly have $f(x) < \xi + L$ for all $x$.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I just discovered that I can only accept one answer and voted for the one of Crostul, as I personally think it's more elegant.